# Upgrade to Jquery Mobile 1.3.0 causes element to be forced to bottom

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have recently decided to upgrade my web app to implement the new jQuery Mobile Panel widget.

After changing to 1.3.0, a `<p>`element on a page in my app is being forced to the bottom. When I reverted back to 1.2.0, the element stayed at the top of the listview like I want it to.

A snippet of my source:

```
    <?php include ('header.php'); ?>        
        <?php print ' <p style="text-align: center;">Welcome, <span style="font-weight:bold; color: orange;">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>! Your user ID is <span style="font-weight:bold; color: orange;">'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'</span>.</p>'; ?>         
        <div data-role="content" id="assignment_list">      
            <!-- create 2 foreach loops, 1 for classes to be listed and organized by id in list dividers and another for listing individual assignments within each class -->   
            <ul data-role="listview">

            <!--classes loop-->

            <?php foreach ($userclasses as $class) : ?>

                <li data-role="list-divider"><?php echo $class['class_name']; ?></li>

                <?php $assignments=get_assignments_by_class($class['class_id']); ?> 
                <?php foreach ($assignments as $assignment) : ?><!--assignments loop-->
                <?php print'<li><a href="index.php?action=show_assign_details&assign_id='.$assignment['assign_id'].'&class_id='.$assignment['class_id'].'">'.$assignment['assign_title'].'</a></li>';?>
                <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/assignments loop-->
            <?php endforeach; ?> <!--/classes loop-->

            </ul>       
        </div><!--/data-role="content"-->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

My goal is to display the user with a message that greets them and signifies they have logged in successfully. I want the message to appear above the listview that displays assignments. It worked fine, but When I changed to jQuery Mobile 1.3.0, the message is now displayed at the bottom of my page, *after* the listview.

I have tried putting the message inside of the content div but it appears cut off.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you print the `<?php print ' <p style="text-align: center;">Welcome, <span style="font-weight:bold; color: orange;">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</span>! Your user ID is <span style="font-weight:bold; color: orange;">'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'</span>.</p>'; ?>` line inside the `content div` before the listview?

I hope that will solve the issue.

Also I hope you are using jQuery 1.9.X?

Comment: I tried putting my print statement inside the content div and it worked this time. Thank you. I found out why I was having problems with it not working the first time. My app uses a listview that spans the full width of the device. They include negative margins and can cause overlap when stacked with other widgets and content such as my simple paragraph. That's why my text was being cut off the first time I tried it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If the answer helped you consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: By the way, [jQuery Mobile 1.3.0](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/) supports the jQuery core 1.7.2 – 1.9.1 and soon 2.0 Beta. The current version of core I'm using is 1.8.2 and I have no issue from that. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: yeap I know, but certain methods such as `live()` depreciated from 1.9.x. if you have them in your code, it'll break.